# foldLeft sum values with BigDecimal.ZERO start value

Tags: scala, functional-programming, bigdecimal, foldleft

I have requirement where I want sum values of all employee salaries in list

```
employeeList.foldLeft(java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO) { (accSal,emp) => accSal + getSalary(emp,designation,yearsOfExp) }
```

Here for each employee I want to call a function getSalary and sum the return values to get salaries of all employees

The above code does not seem to work for me , Keep getting error

```
Type mismatch expected:String actual:BigDecimal
```

Comment: @jwvh I don't see why case is useful. foldLeft expects a two-arg function, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative to Mario's answer, if `getSalary` returns a `java.math.BigDecimal`, and the `fold` should also return one, instead of a `scala.math.BigDecimal`.
You can do this:

```
employeeList.foldLeft(java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO) {
  (accSal, emp) =>
    accSal.add(getSalary(emp,designation,yearsOfExp))
}
```

You can check the [**javadoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to confirm that they do not have a `+` method, but an `add` one.
And for that reason, it was calling the `+` method that returns **Strings**.

Answer (score 4):

Try `scala.BigDecimal(0)` instead of `java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO`, perhaps something like so

```
employeeList.foldLeft(BigDecimal(0)) { (accSal, emp) => accSal + getSalary(emp) }
```

Comment: Hi @Mario , I upvoted your answer and accepted Luis answer as the correct answer , As i had to keep the return type as java.math.BigDecimal